# Catch playlists on iOS HTTP Live Stream (hls)

Tags: ios, xmlhttprequest, http-live-streaming

Since iOS can't use libraries like HLS.js which can easily catch .ts files and playlist I had to use their native support.
I just can't seem to figure out how to catch the playlists and the chunks themselves.
Playlists are loaded just by being placed as a source on a video tag:

```
<video src="https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8" controls>
```

I can see the playlists and the fragments as responses in the Chrome debugger under the "Other" tab. Is there any way to catch the response data?
Thank you.

Comment: What to you mean by “catch” them? As in see the network traffic in a debug window?

Comment: Detect when a request has been made and once it gets a response, get the response data. In the form of an ArrayBuffer or such.

Comment: Your only hope is a service worker, but I doubt it will work.